# jQuery serialize and insert in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this code to insert some data that comes from a while, in a db. I'm trying to use jQuery serializearray and jQuery post together. But it seems I do some errors

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM barcode_prodotti";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo'
    <input type="text" name="prodotto[]" class="prodotto" value="'.$row["prodotto"].'"></div>
    <input type="text" name="prezzo[]" class="price" value="'.$row["prezzo"].'">
    <input type="text" name="quantita[]" class="price" value="'.$row["quantita"].'">';
  }
  ?>
  <script src="js/mine.js"></script>
  <button>Serialize form values</button>
  </form>
  <div id="results"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code I put in mine.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('form').submit(function(msg) {  
var mia =$(this).serialize();
$('#results').text(mia)
alert($(this).serialize()); // check to show that all form data is being submitted
$.post("testtest.php",$(this).serializeArray(),function(data){
    alert(data);                       
});
return false; });
});
```

This is my php file (testtest.php)

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db");  


$arr = $_POST; 

$sql="INSERT INTO table VALUES(
    '".$arr['prodotto']."',
    '".$arr['quantita']."',
    '".$arr['prezzo']."'
)";

$rssql = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

So I the serialize is ok (i tried to assign in a div a value to see if it was ok), but I can't insert values in my db

Comment: Apart from using the _deprecated_ mysql functions and your code being prone to SQL Injection, what exact errors or unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: The data prodotto, prezzo and quantita dont go in mysql table named table

Comment: did you try `echo $arr['prodotto'];` and see what you got before inserting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query ends up looking like this after variable substitution.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES( 'product', '123', '321')
```

If your `table` has exactly three columns this will work fine. Otherwise it will fail.  You may wish to use this query instead.

```
INSERT INTO table (prodotto, prezzo, quantita ) VALUES( 'product', '123', '321')
```

which enumerates the columns where you want your data.

After doing an insert (and after any query) you should check for errors. This can be done with code like this.

```
$res = mysql_query($q);
if ($res === false) {
    echo $mysql_error ();
}
```

*Note well:* The `mysql_xxx()` interface is being removed from PHP for a good reason: it is vulnerable to cybercriminals. Please adopt `mysqli_xxx()` or `PDO` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="prodotto" id="prodotto">
<input type="text" name="prezzo" id="prezzo">
<input type="text" name="quantita" id="quantita">
</form>
```

Jquery is pretty simple too:

```
var datastring = $("#myform").serialize();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'url/to/yourfile.php',
data: datastring
}).done(function(res){
var res = $.trim(res); //the ajax response. you can alert it or whatever...
});
```

You can parse the fields in the ajax file like that:

yourfile.php

```
<?php
$product = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["prodotto"]);
$prezzo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["prezzo"]);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["quantita"]);

//here you have the variables ready to add them as values to database
$ins = "INSERT INTO table (prodotto, prezzo, quantita ) VALUES( 'product', '123', '321')";
mysql_query($ins);

?>
```